# Selecting specific elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose we have the following list:

```
l={{"a"}, {"a", "d"}, {"a", "d"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "b", "d"}, {"a", 
  "b", "c"}, {"a", "c", "d"}, {"a", "b", "d"}, {"a", "d"}, {"b", "d"}}
```

I want to count those entries that have "a","d" in them, I tried the following:

```
Select[l, # == {"a", "d"} &] // Length
```

which gives 3, yet there are other entries that have "a" and "d" in them and the output must be,

```
{{"a", "d"}, {"a", "d"}, {"a", "b", "d"}, {"a", "c", "d"}, {"a", "b", "d"}, {"a", "d"}}
```

which has length 6. How does one solve this?

Comment: `Select[l, ContainsAll[{"a", "d"}]]`

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use either of the following with `Length`:

```
Select[l, ContainsAll[{"a", "d"}]]

Cases[l, {___, "a", ___, "d", ___}]
```

Alternatively, if all you care is the number of occurrences, and not the occurrences themselves, you could use `Count`:

```
Count[l, {___, "a", ___, "d", ___}]
```